# Angular 10 with nodejs - http client POST

Tags: node.js, angular, http, post

I have the following setup on my development machine so everything is running on the same pc (all pretty new to me so forgive the newbie questions)

Angular 10 as the front end
nodejs as the back end server

I am having problems sending http client Post command from Angular to nodejs

When I send the following command after a form has been saved it seems to works the very first time. I can then send it a second time but after that nodesjs doesn't seem to pick up on any more POST requests until I refresh the page.

```
this.httpClient.post('http://localhost:3000/saveConfigSettings', formData).subscribe(
      (response) => console.log(response),
      (error) => console.log(error)
    );
```

The problem looks like it's either not always sending the data from Angular or it's not always getting routed to the right destination. (Could be wrong on this)

- I can see the data in the network tab of developer chrome when I press the save button which sends the post command above
- I have installed cors in node to make sure it isn't something like this blocking the requests
- When I send the same command from Postman, node picks up on it all the time (not an expert in Postman so possibly other tools built in that can help debug)
- Angular is running on port 4200 on the same pc

---

1. It is something to do with subscribe and unsubscribe?
2. Am I configuring the post command incorrectly?
3. What can case http post command to be sporadic?

Here is the component .ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { MatTabChangeEvent } from '@angular/material/tabs';
import { PartService } from '../part.service';
import { Part } from '../part';
import { State } from '../State';

import { FormGroup, FormControl } from '@angular/forms';
import { Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { FormBuilder } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-part-side-nav',
  templateUrl: './part-side-nav.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./part-side-nav.component.css']
})
export class PartSideNavComponent implements OnInit {

  parentForm = new FormGroup({
    // name: new FormControl('', ),
    // cadFileName: new FormControl('',),    
    xIncrement: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
    confidence: new FormControl('' ,Validators.required), 
    yIncrement: new FormControl('' ,Validators.required),
    zIncrement: new FormControl('' ,Validators.required),    
    distance: new FormControl('' ,Validators.required), 
    exposure: new FormControl('' ,Validators.required), 
    number_of_iterations: new FormControl('' ,Validators.required), 
    canny_threshold: new FormControl('' ,Validators.required), 
    fine_pose_alg_type: new FormControl('' ,Validators.required), 
    scaling_factor_rough: new FormControl('' ,Validators.required), 
    scaling_factor_fine: new FormControl('' ,Validators.required), 
    adjust_fine_pose: new FormControl('' ,Validators.required), 
    contour_removal_size: new FormControl('' ,Validators.required), 
    
  });


  constructor(private partService: PartService, private fb: FormBuilder, private httpClient: HttpClient) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  tabChanged = (tabChangeEvent: MatTabChangeEvent): void => {
     
    if (tabChangeEvent.index === 0)
      this.partService.stateDisplay = State.CAD;
    else if (tabChangeEvent.index === 1)
      this.partService.stateDisplay = State.image;  
  }

  onSubmit() {
    
    console.log("onSubmit called");

            
    var formData: any = new FormData();    
    formData.append("name", this.partService.getActivePart().name);
    formData.append("cadFileName", this.partService.getActivePart().cadFileName);    
    formData.append("xIncrement", this.parentForm.get('xIncrement').value);    
    formData.append("yIncrement", this.parentForm.get('yIncrement').value);    
    formData.append("zIncrement", this.parentForm.get('zIncrement').value);    
    formData.append("distance", this.parentForm.get('distance').value);        
    formData.append("exposure", this.parentForm.get('exposure').value);    
    formData.append("confidence", this.parentForm.get('confidence').value);    
    formData.append("number_of_iterations", this.parentForm.get('number_of_iterations').value);    
    formData.append("canny_threshold", this.parentForm.get('canny_threshold').value);    
    formData.append("fine_pose_alg_type", this.parentForm.get('fine_pose_alg_type').value);    
    formData.append("scaling_factor_rough", this.parentForm.get('scaling_factor_rough').value);    
    formData.append("scaling_factor_fine", this.parentForm.get('scaling_factor_fine').value);    
    formData.append("adjust_fine_pose", this.parentForm.get('adjust_fine_pose').value);    
    formData.append("contour_removal_size", this.parentForm.get('contour_removal_size').value);        
    

    this.httpClient.post('http://localhost:3000/saveConfigSettings', formData).subscribe(
      (response) => console.log(response),
      (error) => console.log(error)
    );

    // clear the formData obj used above
    var formDataCad = new FormData();
    formDataCad.append("name", this.partService.getActivePart().name);
    formDataCad.append("cadFileName", this.partService.getActivePart().cadFileName);
    formDataCad.append("cadFileContents", this.partService.getActivePart().cadFileContents);    
    
    this.httpClient.post('http://localhost:3000/saveCad', formDataCad).subscribe(
      (response) => console.log(response),
      (error) => console.log(error)
    );

    // clear the formData obj used above
    var formDataImage = new FormData();
    formDataImage.append("name", this.partService.getActivePart().name);
    formDataImage.append("image", this.partService.getActivePart().image); 
    
    
    this.httpClient.post('http://localhost:3000/saveImage', formDataImage).subscribe(
      (response) => console.log(response),
      (error) => console.log(error)
    );

  }

}
```

And this is the html file associated with this component

<

```
div class="container">

  <div class="flex-container" fxLayout="column">

    <form [formGroup]="parentForm" fxLayout="column" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">

      <mat-tab-group fxFlex color="primary" (selectedTabChange)="tabChanged($event)" >            
       
        <mat-tab fxFlex label="Generate Database">
          <app-generate-database [parentForm]="parentForm"> </app-generate-database> 
        </mat-tab>

        <mat-tab fxFlex label="Image">
          <app-image [parentForm]="parentForm"></app-image>
        </mat-tab>      
        
      </mat-tab-group>

      <button fxFlex type="submit" color="primary" fxFlex [disabled]="!parentForm.valid" mat-button>Save</button>

    </form>

      
  </div>
</div>
```

This is a testPost I am sending to try and figure out what is going on. When it's successful, in the network tab in chrome I get this

[image]

When it doesn't send I get this which is very different. Anyone any ideas?

[image]

Comment: Hi, can you please share your entire component code? The piece you put looks good

Comment: just added the .ts file. Thanks in advance

Comment: This looks good again to me. If you want try to share a complete stackblitz example. 
Are you using ngSubmit like explained here? (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()"
https://angular.io/start/start-forms

Comment: just added the html side of things. Each time I click on the save button I can see it's calling the OnSubmit function. Just can't figure out why it would do it twice and then stop until I refresh the browser window. Not sure how to show all this on stackblitz.

Comment: wondering if this is a cors issue. If it was could it behave like this or would it just not work all the time? How would you tell? Just tried a much simpler onSubmit and it worked for 5 or POSTs and then stopped working

Comment: Open the dev tools and check the "Network" tab - it should give you idea whether a) the request is sent or not and what actually happens with the request - does it time out? Does it return an error?

Comment: Just tried this and I don't get any errors but I did notice there is a difference between the information in the headers for a successful vs nothing sent. I've added the images to the main question. No idea what this means though? any ideas?

Comment: OK - I think I may have figured this out. It looks like it was on the nodejs side of things. When I was handling the post command in nodejs and express I wasn't sending anything back as a response to angular component. Can someone clarify Is this something that has to be done or just good practice?